# A second glossary to be treated like acronyms

Tags: glossaries, acronyms, split

I'm writing a thesis with a lot of chemicals named, and I'd quite like them to be fully expressed when they first appear in the text, and then just as acronyms further onwards, so for instance (2-(9H-carbazol-9-yl)ethyl)phosphonic acid (2PACz) the first time and then 2PACz from there on after. The obvious way to do it would be to define them as acronyms, but there are so many, and they have such long names, that my acronym list becomes borderline unreadable. I'd also like to make the chemicals glossary a bit more useful if I can, to list a few extra infos on the chemicals.

It seems like it should be possible to do this with a separate glossary, but I have not found any information on the forum. I don't know if this has been done before or even really how to even search for it, so if this has been answered before, I apologize.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image]

Here's how you could use the `acro` package in order to get two separate lists, one of them with extra information on each item.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{acro}

\DeclareAcronym{2PACz}{
  short = 2PACz,
  long = (2-(9H-carbazol-9-yl)ethyl)phosphonic acid,
  extra = some extra information text that is only shown in the list of chemicals, 
  tag= chemical
}

\DeclareAcronym{rt}{
  short = rt,
  long = room temperature,
}

\begin{document}

first use: \ac{2PACz} and \ac{rt}

subsequent use: \ac{2PACz} and \ac{rt}

\printacronyms[sort=true, exclude=chemical]
\printacronyms[sort=true, include=chemical, name=List of chemicals]

\end{document}
```

---

If you prefer a `glossaries`-based approach, here is how you could use that package to get an almost identical output:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[acronyms,shortcuts,nonumberlist,automake]{glossaries}
\makeglossaries

\newglossaryentry{2PACz}
    {type=main, 
     name={2PACz}, 
     description={(2-(9H-carbazol-9-yl)ethyl)phosphonic acid,  some extra information text that is only shown in the list of chemicals}, 
     first={(2-(9H-carbazol-9-yl)ethyl)phosphonic acid (2PACz)\glsadd{2PACz}}}

\newacronym{rt}{rt}{room temperature}


\begin{document}

first use: \ac{2PACz} and \ac{rt}

subsequent use: \ac{2PACz} and \ac{rt}

\printglossary[type=acronym]
\printglossary[title=List of Chemicals, type=main]

\end{document}
```

Comment: Is this compatible with the glossaries package? That is what is being used in the template I have, but I can rewrite it.

Comment: @RedRaceCat: I would not recommend combining `glossaries` and `acro` in the same document. I updated my answer to also include a `glossaries`-based approach that results in an almost identical output.

Comment: That works a treat, thank you very much!